# Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Undefined variable: post (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\GoHelp\resources\views\posts\index.blade.php) ..laravel 7

Tags: laravel

---

- Please help , I am not able to retrive data in my view i get this
  error: Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
  Undefined variable: post (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\GoHelp\resources\views\posts\index.blade.php): post i tried almost everything possible.

---

..... this is my controller ......

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
    $users = User::all();
    return view('posts.index',compact('posts', 'users'));
}
```

.......  this is my index.blade.php........

```
@section('content')

 @if($post->count()>0)
@foreach ($post as $posts )
  <div class="container">
    <h2></h2>
      <div class="panel-heading">Request No:{{ $posts->id }} </div>
        <h3>
          <a href=" /posts/{{ $posts->id }} "><text>Pick up poin : </text>
          {{ $posts->pick_up}}
          </a>
        </h3>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <h3>Drop off : {{ $posts->drop_off}}
        </h3></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <h3>Date : {{ $posts->date}}
          </h3></div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h3>Time : {{ $posts->time}}
            </h3></div>
    </div>
  </div>
@endforeach
{{ $post->links() }}
@else
<div class="alert alert-info"
<strong>Ops</strong> No Posts
</div>
@endif
}}
@section('css')
      <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  @stop
  @section('javascript')
      <script src="{{ ('js/app.js') }}"></script>
  @stop
@endsection
```

..........the routes ........

```
  Auth::routes();
    
    
    Route::get('/', 'PagesController@home');
    Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about');
    Route::get('/contact', 'PagesController@contact');
    Route::resource('/posts','postsController');
    Route::get('posts','postsController@index');
    
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::resource('/user','UserController');
    
    Route::get('/donate', function(){
      return view('pages.Donate');
    });
    Route::get('/BecomeDriver', function(){
      return view('pages.BecomeDriver');
    });
    Route::get('/admin/Dashboard', function(){
      return view('admin.Dashboard');
    });
    Route::get('/General_Login_Page', function(){
      return view('General_Login_Page');
    });
    
    
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
         // admin routes
    Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
        // Dashboard route
        Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
    
      // Driver Routes
      Route::prefix('driver')->group(function () {
          // Dashboard route
          Route::get('/', 'DriverController@index')->name('driver.dashboard');
```

......... the model ......

```
 class Post extends Model
{
  public function user()
 {
   return $this->belongsTo('app\User');
 }
public function driver()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
}
```

..............migration table (creat_posts_table)......

```
public function up()
 {
     Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->increments('id');
         $table->text('pick_up');
         $table->text('drop_off');
         $table->date('date');
         $table->time('time');
         $table->timestamps();
     });
 }
```

Comment: It would be `@foreach ($posts as $post)`

Answer (score 0):

You pass the `posts` variable,  not `post`,  change like that :

```
@if($posts->count()>0)
@foreach ($posts as $post )
  <div class="container">
    <h2></h2>
      <div class="panel-heading">Request No:{{ $post->id }} </div>
        <h3>
          <a href=" /posts/{{ $post->id }} "><text>Pick up poin : </text>
          {{ $post->pick_up}}
          </a>
        </h3>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <h3>Drop off : {{ $post->drop_off}}
        </h3></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <h3>Date : {{ $post->date}}
          </h3></div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h3>Time : {{ $post->time}}
            </h3></div>
    </div>
  </div>
@endforeach
{{ $posts->links() }}
@else
```